# Value error while writing from one csv file to another using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, file

I am writing a code that goes through many csv files in a folder(using a for loop), removes bad data from each csv file(where row values are more than number of columns or sometimes lesser than number of columns). After removing, I rearrange the columns and then I write the useful data into a new csv file.
Here in the code below the for loop is for cycling between different files present in a folder. You can assume the `df=pd.read_csv` line as the beginning and assume correct indentation.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

for filename in os.listdir("csv files copy"):
    filenames=os.path.join("csv files copy",filename)
    print(filename)
   
    df=pd.read_csv(filenames, error_bad_lines=False)

    for row in df:

        df.columns=["id","FirstName","LastName","UserName","Phone","IsContact","RestrictionReason","Status","IsScam","Date"]
        df = df.drop(labels="Status", axis=1)
        df = df.reindex(columns=['id', 'Phone', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'UserName',"IsContact","IsScam","Date","RestrictionReason"])
        df.to_csv(filenames,index=False)
```

While doing so this is the error I recieve.
`ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 9 elements, new values have 10 elements`

This is the first 4 values and the header of the dataframe that I am using:

```
id                      Phone   FirstName   LastName   UserName     IsContact  IsScam Date                       RestrictionReason        Status             
Forex Pips Fire Free    NaN     Goldenboy      NaN     Goldenboyys      False   False  5/7/2022 8:34:07 AM                NaN             NaN
Forex Pips Fire Free    NaN     Abu 3odeh      NaN         oudah12      False   False  5/7/2022 8:38:03 AM                NaN             NaN
Forex Pips Fire Free    NaN        Rahman     Azar     Rahman_Azar      False   False  5/7/2022 8:41:22 AM                NaN             NaN
Forex Pips Fire Free    NaN         HUDLE      NaN       Hudle1051      False   False  5/7/2022 8:41:11 AM                NaN             NaN
```

And given below is the header of the destination csv file that the above data needs to be entered into

```
id Phone FirstName LastName UserName IsContact IsScam Date RestrictionReason
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the for loop as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

for filename in os.listdir("csv files copy"):
    filenames = os.path.join("csv files copy", filename)
    print(filename)
   
    df = pd.read_csv(filenames, error_bad_lines=False)
    df.columns = ["id", "FirstName", "LastName", "UserName", "Phone", "IsContact", "RestrictionReason", "Status", "IsScam", "Date"]
    df = df.drop(labels="Status", axis=1)
    df = df.reindex(columns=["id", "Phone", "FirstName", "LastName", "UserName","IsContact","IsScam","Date","RestrictionReason"])
    df.to_csv(filenames, index=False)
```

This was causing the error and is not needed. The first time through the loop it correctly removes `Status` column and saves the CSV file. The second time through the loop (on the same dataframe) it attempts to do `df.columns` again but now there is no  `Status` column, so an incorrect number of columns are given.

The code `for row in df:` would actually iterate over the column names in the dataframe,
e.g. `id` then `FirstName` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because you give only 9 columns in this line you missed the `'Status'` column

```py
df = df.reindex(columns=['id', 'Phone', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'UserName', 'IsContact', 'IsScam', 'Date', 'RestrictionReason'])
df.to_csv(filenames, index=False)
```

Comment: `df = df.drop(labels="Status", axis=1)` but I've written the code to delete that column before reindexing